# Set visualforce page in listing of custom object

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

I have created one custom object. I have added list of this object in tab menu. I need to add two buttons in listing page so I have created visual force page. I am trying to configure this page in list page but I am not getting my page in listing.

[image]
[image]

Please help me.

Following is the code of visualforce page

```
<apex:page Standardcontroller="Contract_History__c" extensions="ContractHistoryListController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock >
          <center><apex:outputText rendered="{!(ContractHistoryList.size = 0)}" style="font-weight: bold;" value="There are no records available in a contract history." /></center>          
        <apex:pageblockTable value="{!ContractHistoryList}" var="c" id="CHTable" rendered="{!(ContractHistoryList.size != 0)}">    
           <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                   <apex:outputlink value="https://cs1.salesforce.com/{!c.id}" >{!c.Name}</apex:outputlink>
                </apex:column> 
       <!-- <apex:column value="{!c.Name}"/>--> 
        <apex:column value="{!c.Account_Name__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!c.Contract_User_Name__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!c.Contract_Name__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!c.Contact_Name__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!c.Type__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!c.Status__c}"/>
    </apex:pageblockTable>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">

                <apex:commandButton value="Migrate Contract Users" id="btnContractUsers" action="{!AddContractUsersToContractHistory}" oncomplete="window.opener.location.refresh();" />                              

                <apex:commandButton value="Migrate Contract Members" id="btnContractMembers" action="{!AddContractMembersToContractHistory}" oncomplete="window.opener.location.refresh();" />                          


        </apex:pageBlockButtons>      

         </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **recordSetVar** attribute on your  component. This is required for overiding the list button. The fist line in VF page should look like this `<apex:page Standardcontroller="Contract_History__c" recordSetVar="list_contacthistory" extensions="ContractHistoryListController">`

More about recordSetVar http://salesforcedeveloperblog.blogspot.in/2011/07/recordsetvar-tag-in-visualforce-page.html.

If this helps you mark it as answer.